# Custom extension for Autodesk Forge Viewer in Fusion Team 360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

I've created a simple web application to show and test the power of the Autodesk Forge Viewer: a custom extension makes something important for the customer.

Now the customer wants to use Autodesk Fusion Team 360 and asks me if my custom extension can be embedded in the standard viewer of Autodesk Fusion Team 360.

I've found no official answer: a lot of material about Autodesk BIM 360 platform, but nothing about Autodesk Fusione Team 360.

Have you ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Fusion 360 Team is a storage service for Fusion files, In the UI of the product you cannot load extension, the best thing to do will be to use Data Management API to read your customer data (with his approval through 3 legged authentication) and load his models in your custom Viewer application where you can load other extensions he desires to use.